# foreach can't operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' doesn't contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
private void pckItemCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;
            int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectedIndex != -1)
            {

                var field = picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];

                foreach (var data2 in field)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I Want to get data from ItemSource, when i looping data from var field, i get an error .. what should i do ?

Comment: in page load i'm already set the picker.itemsource, and i want to set value of another textbox based on picker SelectedItem

Comment: I am assuming you know the type to be expected. And that type seems to be some sort of collection type. So, you need to cast it to that type, then iterate it.

Comment: The error is telling you the exact problem. `field` is of type `object` and the compiler isn't sure it is enumerable so cannot iterate over it. If it is enumerable (e.g. a `List<string>`) then you need to cast it to something the compiler understands.

Comment: are you trying to iterate over the properties of an object?  There are many existing questions about how to do that with reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void pckItemCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;
            int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

            if (selectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var field = picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];

                foreach (var propertyInfo in field.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                        string test = propertyInfo.GetValue(field).ToString();
                        string test2 = propertyInfo.Name;
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally i am found this answer, i want to get property value from object and i get it.. thanks to everyone who helped answer my question

Comment: Please accept your reply as an answer. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I Know, but i can mark my reply as an answer after 1 day after my reply created

Comment: Ok, thank you for your support for xamarin. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access the property of the selected object, right?

Then, you can get the selected object by the `selectedIndex` just as your code, and we can access the properties of the selected object by  casting the object into the type of the item of the Picker.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            // here you can cast the field to your type,mine is `Monkey `
            Monkey field = (Monkey)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--------> "+ selectedIndex+"<---->" + field.Name);

        }
    }
```

Note:

Since the `field` is not a list, so we cann't iterate over `field`

```
foreach (var data2 in field) // Code usage error
            {

            }
```